# How to make sure that -- print {\bf --}?

Tags: tex-core, typography

In French typography, a medium dash, with spaces before and after, is used in places where the English uses an em-dash.

But the medium dash of TeX is much thinner than the dashes used in French print shops. So I would like to replace it with `{\bf --}`.

Unfortunately,  `--` is not a macro which could be redefined using `\let` and `\def`.

Comment: You can define it yourself: `\newcommand{\fdash}{\textbf{--}}`

Comment: note that `\bf` is not defined by default in latex.

Comment: Try `---` instead of `--`...

Answer (score 2):

If nothing is defined formally, define it yourself:

```
\newcommand{\fdash}{\textbf{--}}
```

Now you can

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\fdash}{\textbf{--}}

\begin{document}

This is -- some regular stuff.

This is \fdash{} some awesome stuff!

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can redefine the — (em dash, Unicode U+2014) to do what you want:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2014}{\textbf{--}}
\begin{document}
    This is a TeX plain -- en-dash

    This is a Unicode — em-dash

    This is a TeX --- ligature
\end{document}
```

[image]